# Window docker is not picking cuda on WSL2

Tags: python, windows, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed Ubuntu `20.04.2` LTS on windows 11 (OS build 22000.100) using WSL2.
When I do `nvidia-smi`, it shows me GPU.
But when I run the docker image it gave the following error

```
RuntimeError: Found no NVIDIA driver on your system. Please check that you have an NVIDIA GPU and installed a driver from http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx
```

I am using docker windows on wsl2. When I do `uname -r` i got `5.10.43.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2`

Is there any solution?

Comment: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have the supported driver (https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl/download, free registration required), update Docker Desktop to the latest version, and then run `docker run --rm -it --gpus=all nvcr.io/nvidia/k8s/cuda-sample:nbody` to test it out. You then have to run your containers with `--gpus=all`.